# compile oracle form

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

I want to know, can I compile oracle forms without using Oracle Form Builder?

I mean is there any command for compile them without open the oracle form? I am using a batch file for compile them, but for each file it open one time oracle form & close it, so I can not do any thing else...  please advice me.

I need it for Oracle forms 6i & 10g forms.

I need log file as well if any error hits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The progam `frmcmp` can be run from the command line to compile a single form:

```
frmcmp userid=un/pw module=%%f batch=yes module_type=form compile_all=yes window_state=minimize
```

To do many you need to create a batch file (assuming on Windows) like:

```
for %%f IN (*.fmb) do frmcmp userid=un/pw module=%%f batch=yes module_type=form compile_all=yes window_state=minimize
```

Any errors are written to a file with the same name as the form but with extension ".err".